# Reference issue with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects cached on client side using JS array.

```
var scannerDictionary = new Array();            //Holds all scanners unmodified
var modifiedScannerDictionary = new Array();    //Holds all scanners with modified values
```

The properties of each object is set/changed using GUI and updated in the object. Each object contains list of InputParameters (array of Parameter class containing Name, Value and other members).

Please have a look on GUI.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Below is the code i used to render the controls -

```
function renderControls(scannerId) {
        var currentScanner = modifiedScannerDictionary[scannerId];

        //Render Input Parameters
        $("#tblInputCriteria").find('tr:gt(5)').remove();
        for(var i=0;i<currentScanner.InputParameters.length;i++) {
            var propType = currentScanner.InputParameters[i].DataType;
            var inParName = currentScanner.InputParameters[i].Name;

            switch(propType) {
                case 0: //Number
                    var eRow1 = $("#tblInputCriteria").find('#emptyNumRow').clone();
                    $(eRow1).removeClass('hidden').attr('id', 'Row_'+currentScanner.InputParameters[i].Name);
                    $(eRow1).appendTo($('#tblInputCriteria'));
                    var prop1 = $(eRow1).find('#InNumPropName');
                    $(prop1).attr('id', 'InNumPropName_'+currentScanner.InputParameters[i].Name);
                    var propName1 = currentScanner.InputParameters[i].Name;
                    $(prop1).html(propName1);
                    var propVal1 = $(eRow1).find('#InNumPropValue');
                    $(propVal1).attr('id', 'InNumPropValue_'+currentScanner.InputParameters[i].Name);
                    $(propVal1).val(currentScanner.InputParameters[i].Value);
                    $(propVal1).blur(function () {
                        if(!ValidateNumber(this, propName1)) {
                            alert('Value should be numeric in ' + propName1);
                            setTimeout(function() {$(propVal1).focus();}, 100);
                        }else {
                            UpdateData(currentScanner.Id, propName1, $(propVal1).val());
                        }
                    });

                    break;
                case 1: //String
                    var eRow2 = $("#tblInputCriteria").find('#emptyStrRow').clone();
                    $(eRow2).removeClass('hidden').attr('id', 'Row_'+currentScanner.InputParameters[i].Name);
                    $(eRow2).appendTo($('#tblInputCriteria'));
                    var prop2 = $(eRow2).find('#InStrPropName');
                    $(prop2).attr('id', 'InStrPropName_'+currentScanner.InputParameters[i].Name);
                    var propName2 = currentScanner.InputParameters[i].Name;
                    $(prop2).html(propName2);
                    var propVal2 = $(eRow2).find('#InStrPropValue');
                    $(propVal2).attr('id', 'InStrPropValue_'+currentScanner.InputParameters[i].Name);
                    $(propVal2).val(currentScanner.InputParameters[i].Value);
                    $(propVal2).blur(function () {
                        UpdateData(currentScanner.Id, propName2, $(propVal2).val());
                    });
                    break;
                case 2: //Boolean
                    var eRow3 = $("#tblInputCriteria").find('#emptyBoolRow').clone();
                    $(eRow3).removeClass('hidden').attr('id', 'Row_'+currentScanner.InputParameters[i].Name);
                    $(eRow3).appendTo($('#tblInputCriteria'));
                    var prop3 = $(eRow3).find('#InBoolPropName');
                    $(prop3).attr('id', 'InBoolPropName_'+currentScanner.InputParameters[i].Name);
                    var propName3 = currentScanner.InputParameters[i].Name;
                    $(prop3).html(propName3);
                    var propVal3 = $(eRow3).find('#InBoolPropValue');
                    $(propVal3).attr('id', 'InBoolPropValue_'+currentScanner.InputParameters[i].Name);
                    $(propVal3).val(currentScanner.InputParameters[i].Value);
                    $(propVal3).blur(function () {
                        UpdateData(currentScanner.Id, propName3, $(propVal3).val());
                    });
                    break;
    }
}
}
```

PROBLEM:
The problem here is of the variables inside switch working as reference variable. So the `UpdateData()` function gets the last Name for similar type properties. i.e. if fields are of Number type then only the last property is updated by `UpdateData()` method.

Can anybody help me out solve this issue. Thanks for sharing your time and wisdom.

Comment: Most common problem #2: Closures inside a loop. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: @Bergi: How to return data from an Ajax call... could also be vice versa ;)

Comment: Thanks Felix for your quick reply on this with useful link as well, +1 for that.

Comment: @FelixKling  I believe you actually link to the answer.  If the questioner simply assigns the 'currentScanner' object to a variable within the anon function for .blur() they should be fine.

Comment: @Robert could you be more specific with some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following.  Its a tad overkill, but will bind the values of the variables to the closures.

```
var fnOnBlur = (function(thePropName, thePropVal) {
    return function () {
        if(!ValidateNumber(this, thePropName)) {
            alert('Value should be numeric in ' + thePropName);
            setTimeout(function() {$(thePropVal).focus();}, 100);
        }else {
            UpdateData(currentScanner.Id, thePropName, $(thePropVal).val());
        }
    };
})(propName1, propVal1);
$(propVal1).blur( fnOnBlur );
```

The link that Felik King supplied has much more detailed discussion.

Comment: Thanks Robert for your reply.